# Wav sound is not playing in react

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm getting the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.", while trying to play a wav sound file using react-sound and "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type." in a three.js scene using a positionalAudio. It works when I use mp3 files. I already tried to fix it by importing the wav file through file-loader and a webpack config. On the dev and build server everything works also using wav files but after deplyoing to a cloudflare server I'm getting this error when I try to use wav.
Now my second guess is, that I somehow have to set to code up using a promise but I am struggling as how to do it.

Code for react-sound

```
import Sound from 'react-sound'
import wavURL from '../../../public/sounds/ambientStereoSound.wav'

export default function AmbientSound(props) {
  let state = ''
  if(props.state){
      state = Sound.status.PLAYING
  }else{
      state = Sound.status.PAUSED
  }
  
  return (
    <Sound
      url={wavURL}
      autoLoad={true}
      playStatus={state}
      loop={true}
      volume={100}
    />
  )
}
```

Code for three.js (react-three-fiber)

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import React, { Suspense, useMemo, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useThree, useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { PositionalAudioHelper } from 'three/examples/jsm/helpers/PositionalAudioHelper.js'
import { useControls } from 'leva'

function PositionalAudio({ refs, url, volume, rolloffFactor, coneOuterGain, state }) {
  const sound = refs
  const { camera } = useThree()
  const [listener] = useState(() => new THREE.AudioListener())
  const buffer = useLoader(THREE.AudioLoader, url)

  useEffect(() => {
    sound.current.setBuffer(buffer)
    sound.current.setRefDistance(1)
    sound.current.setRolloffFactor(1)
    sound.current.setDirectionalCone(180, 260, 0)
    sound.current.setLoop(true)
    sound.current.setVolume(volume)
    sound.current.play()
    const helper = new PositionalAudioHelper(sound.current)
    sound.current.add(helper)
    camera.add(listener)
    return () => camera.remove(listener)
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    sound.current.setDirectionalCone(180, 260, coneOuterGain)
    sound.current.setRolloffFactor(rolloffFactor)
    sound.current.setVolume(volume)
  }, [rolloffFactor, volume, coneOuterGain])
  if(state) {
    useEffect(() => {
      sound.current.play()
    }, [state])
  }else{
    useEffect(() => {
      sound.current.pause()
    }, [state])
  }
  return <positionalAudio ref={sound} args={[listener]} />
}

type SoundObject = {
  id: number
  x: number
  y: number
  z: number
  position: number[]
  filePath: string
  name: string
  rotation: number
}

type SoundObjectProps = {
  soundObjects: SoundObject[]
}

export default function SoundObject(props: SoundObjectProps) {
  

  const audioRefs = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(props.soundObjects.length)
        .fill(0)
        .map(() => React.createRef()),
    []
  )

  const PositionalSoundObject = props.soundObjects.map((soundObject, index) => {

    const name = soundObject.name

    const { Rotation, Volume, Rolloff, X, Y, Z, ConeOuterGain } = useControls( name, {
      Rotation: {
        value: soundObject.rotation,
        min: 0,
        max: Math.PI * 2,
        step: Math.PI * 0.25
      },
      Volume: {
        value: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.05
      },
      Rolloff: {
        value: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.05
      },
      ConeOuterGain: {
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 1
      },
      X: {
        value: soundObject.x,
      },
      Y: {
        value: soundObject.y,
      },
      Z: {
        value: soundObject.z,
      }
    })

    return (
      <mesh position={[X, Y, Z]} rotation={[0, Rotation, 0]}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.1, 8, 8]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color='hotpink' wireframe />
        <PositionalAudio
          refs={audioRefs[index]}
          volume={Volume}
          rolloffFactor={Rolloff}
          url={soundObject.filePath}
          key={soundObject.id}
          coneOuterGain={ConeOuterGain}
          state={props.state}
        />
      </mesh>
    )
  })
  return <Suspense fallback={null}>{PositionalSoundObject}</Suspense>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why, but hosting the wav files on the server and requesting it through https fixed the problem. My guess is that next.js (which runs node.js) can't handle loading wav files from the public folder out of the box and that it is not a problem related to react.